# swift append to file if exists or create file otherwise

Tags: swift, file

I want to write a String to a file. If the file doesn't exist it should be created.
If it does, the String should be appended.

I tried:

```
    let data = text.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    let filemgr = FileManager.default
    let path = filemgr.urls(for: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, in: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask).last?.appendingPathComponent("out.txt")
    if !filemgr.fileExists(atPath: (path?.absoluteString)!) {
        filemgr.createFile(atPath: (path?.absoluteString)!, contents: data, attributes: nil)
    } else {
        var file = FileHandle(forReadingAtPath: (path?.absoluteString)!)
        let databuffer = String(describing: file?.readDataToEndOfFile())
        file = FileHandle(forWritingAtPath: (path?.absoluteString)!)
        if file != nil {

            file?.seek(toFileOffset: 10)
            file?.write(data!)
            file?.closeFile()
        }
    }
```

so far the file doesn't even seem to get created, since it jumps to the createFile every time. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `(path?.path)!` instead of `(path?.absoluteString)!`.

Comment: thank you, how can I open the file on my device or get it on my computer?

Comment: Do you want to display that data in your application or just want to see that file?

Comment: see the file. best case on my pc, but at least on the device

Comment: Connect you device to mac, Open Xcode, Go to `Window -> Devices & Simulators` , select your device then select your app. Click on last setting button at bottom of this window and click on download button. This contains all data in your app. Here you can see the file in respective directory.

Comment: If you are using simulator then simply copy path of that file from xcode console. Open finder and Go To Finder, Paste your link here and remove file name. It will open your directory in which you have saved your file.

Comment: the container is empty

Comment: do you have .xcappdata file? if yes, Open it as show package contents. It contains all the directory.

Comment: This solution did not work for me.